# error during pass variables one viewController to another controller programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to pass textfields values one viewcontroller to another. I tried following codes with no success:

Frist I tried:

```
var testval = "est val here lalla"
let viewController = BookingConfirmationController(nibName: "BConController", bundle: nil)
                viewController.testval = "test test"
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

when I run this code I could pass variable as expect bit viewController not displayed. Instead I got black screen. I found this nibName is old usage and not use any more. I created  viewContorllers through the storyborad.

Then I tried  below code:

```
var storyboard: UIStoryboard =   UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)


          var testval = " test"

                var vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BConControllerID") as UIViewController

                vc.testval = testval

                self.presentViewController(vc ,animated: true, completion: nil )
```

I'm having an error here as

> UIViewController does not have a member named 'festival'

Without variable I can open next viewController successfully.

I'm still learning SWIFT and can anyone help me to open next view controller and pass variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have custom parameters you should have a subclass of UIViewController. To access it from another class, you have to cast that instance of UIViewController to the subclass you created. In this line

```
var vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BConControllerID") as UIViewController
```

You should have it as something like

```
var vc: myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BConControllerID") as myViewController
```

where myViewController is the custom subclass you have in order to access it's properties.

Also as a side note, it all you are creating is a UIViewController, you do not need to explicitly cast it as instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will return a UIViewController

Comment: I tried like this :   var vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookingConfirmationControllerID") as BConController . But I still get the same error. And I didn't get your sideNote clearly. Could you please explain it bit more.

Comment: maybe you should read up on some basics on the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics), what you did is to declare vc as a UIViewController but store a BConController in. There is no problem since BConController is a subclass of UIViewController but since the compiler is told that vc is a UIViewController and not a BConController, you cannot access BConController's properties even though it is stored. Declare vc like `var vc:BConController` to access it's properties.

Comment: Sorry My mistake. It's working. Thanks for your support.